# django - detect IntegrityError without "save()"

Tags: django

ok, i need a little help here.

I have a model which has a field called `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)`, and i am trying to set this field on `save()` by appending `1` to slug if slug already exists and so on.

I want to consider race conditions.

```
def set_uniqslug(self, slug, i=0):
    new_slug = u"{}{}".format(slug, str(i) if i else '')
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.slug = slugify(new_slug.lower())
            self.save()
            return self
        return self
    except IntegrityError as e:
        i += 1
        return set_uniqslug(self, slug, i)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        set_uniqslug(self.name.lower()) # <--- but it does "save" above. 
        # i want something like:
        # self.slug = self.get_uniqslug(self.name.lower())
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my problem is, if i call the `set_uniqslug()`, it needs to try to save, just to know if there is IntegrityError. in my code, it goes into infinite loop.

how can I know without saving if there is IntegrityError and then just return the unique slug back to `save()` method?

**update**:

i tried this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    if Company.objects.filter(slug=new_slug).exists():
        i += 1
        return self.set_uniqslug(slug, i)
    return new_slug
```

it is working, but i have a stomachache by locking `READ`-action. am I not blocking other queries or doing any other bad stuff by doing this?

Comment: You could prevent the infinite loop by calling the `super().save()` inside the `set_uniqslug()` method - you don't need to call the model `save()` method again. That said, unless you're building a very high volume site, adding a read isn't a huge overhead.

Comment: That said, the fact that storing the slug is an issue that needs googling suggests a simpler slug may be worth considering.

Comment: Consider a `name-pk` slug format, an easier approach to resolve slug conflicts.

Comment: @abstractpaper very good point :)

Comment: @doniyor you also can do something like `pk ^ 0x109ABE7` if you don't feel like exposing your ids to the public

Comment: @abstractpaper what do you mean by ``0x109ABE7 ``?

Comment: @doniyor any hex number, try it: `print 1 ^ 0x109ABE7`

Comment: @abstractpaper oh ok, this is also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check-and-set version will probably not work. That will depend on your database and its implementation of the transaction isolation levels; but taking PostgreSQL as an example, the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level will not prevent another transaction from inserting a row with the same slug in between your check and set.

So use your original, optimistic locking idea. As Hugo Rodger-Brown pointed out, you can avoid the infinite loop by calling the superclass's `save()`.

Finally, you might want to consider an alternative slug format. Many times the slug will incorporate the database id (similar to StackOverflow itself, actually), which eliminates the possibility of duplicate slugs.

Comment: you are right, but i would want to hide id's in url so that no one can know how many company profiles are there in db... but i think, this is better and safer way to go..